# Binding Datagridview Combobox Cell to Int Column in DB / EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-binding, datagridview, combobox

Everytime I try and bind a comboxbox cell column to a field on my entity that is an integer it throws up DataErrors on every row.

I assume this is because its only meant for `string` dropdowns, or atleast from the UI designer atleast, as the collection property allows entry of `string` values.

How do I get it to bind to an integer list?

Also I have an int value `Qty` in my entity. It may be 5. How can I get the combobox cell when showing a row to put 1,2,3,4,5 in the collection and have 5 selected?

Error :
[image]

Comment: What is the error?  And how is the binding defined?

Comment: @AnuragRanjhan you can see the error from the pic. The binding is defined in the designer as a DataPropertyName of Qty ... in the entity its an Int16