# DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid numeric list

Tags: c#, binding, datagridview

it already exist a post with the problem im facing, but its unanswered  [Binding Datagridview Combobox Cell to Int Column in DB / EF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10414380/binding-datagridview-combobox-cell-to-int-column-in-db-ef). The problem occurs when i load the combobox list with database integer fields(1,2,3) and when the cell lose focus it appear the DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid. i already tried with integers in the list with the next code:

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn col = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)this.dataGridView1.Columns["usu_nivel"];
col.Items.Add(1);
col.Items.Add(2);
col.DataPropertyName = "usu_nivel";
```

Comment: Is this your entire binding code?

Comment: I'm not clear on what the problem is exactly, is an error being generated when you use these values? If not can you provide a bit of code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: What is the `DataSource` of your DataGridView? The types and values should be matched. I mean if the binding data of your comboboxColumn is type of `byte` or `short`, then the Item type should also be type of `byte` or `short` respectively.

Comment: @lc. I know the types must match, but i dont know how to fill de combobox with numbers, here is the link of the problem: when you select the integer column and lost focus you will get the error:[link](http://juarezsoft.com.mx/test1.rar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this, the only thing i need to do was to change the type of the field from int16 to string in the automatically generated dataset designer in my case even when the physical access database field was a numeric field.